# typescript template literal types - combine

Tags: typescript

Lets say we have events list:

```
type Events = ['error', 'config', 'ready']
```

And I created types for event handlers

```
 on(event: 'error', listener: Listener);
 on(event: 'config', listener: Listener);
 on(event: 'ready', listener: Listener);
```

I'm struggling to create types for something like this:

```
api.on('error config', (data: any) => any) or
api.on('config error ready', (data: any) => any) etc
```

Can we somehow do it with recursive syntax in TS with template literals?

Thanks!

Comment: What's `Listener`?  Are you trying to correlate the different event names with different parameters?  If you're just trying to get a union of all possible string types, and all `Listener`s are the same `(data: any) => any` type, then you can do it [like this](https://tsplay.dev/Nalaow).  If that meets your needs I'd be happy to write up an answer (or point you to an existing answer); if not, please elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use function overloading, generics and utility types to achieve this:

```js
type APIEvent = 'error' | 'config' | 'ready';

type APIEventHandler = {
    // This signature allows only one event type, from the `APIEvent` union type.
    (event: APIEvent, listener: () => void): void;

    // This signature allows two event types, the first one of type `APIEvent` and the second one `APIEvent` minus whatever the first one is.
    <TEvent extends APIEvent, TEvent2 extends Exclude<APIEvent, TEvent>>(event: `${TEvent} ${TEvent2}`, listener: () => void): void;

    // This signature allows three event types, the first one of type `APIEvent`, the second one `APIEvent` minus whatever the first one is and the third one `APIEvent` minus the first and second parameters.
    <TEvent extends APIEvent, TEvent2 extends Exclude<APIEvent, TEvent>, TEvent3 extends Exclude<APIEvent, TEvent2>>(event: `${TEvent} ${TEvent2} ${TEvent3}`, listener: () => void): void;
}

// Here you would implement the actual behaviour
declare const handler: APIEventHandler;

// These work
handler('error', () => {});
handler('error config', () => {});
handler('error config ready', () => {});

// These do not compile
handler('test', () => {});
handler('error error', () => {});
handler('error config ready ready', () => {});
```

Check out the TypeScript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggCgSQKIDcIDthQLxQOQQBOhA9oXlAD74DGJ6AZgJYDmF1ehEAhgCYh4A3AChhoSLESoMwABLd0vADZEcUAN7Co2qAAoIaTAC5JyQ8AA0UJUwDOwDERO6AlDgB8UFCSa8XJ718RHSgAHgAVaUwoCAAPB0VbUyjLKEjzACYY+IxeJKRYmiUAV14IUPgzGSt0mXd3fXMTAAMAEnVazABfKHbO4Ayu5qsbe0dCZzdsT0C-AJ9eYJ0IlOyEvOTzGpSsuPX8wpKyiqkttJT3bfMAZjXcg6LS8sqUq5kM+saZFr6Unt-Mv8OilrkMRnYEk49FMZgt-F4FiIuqIykVuFwoHR0PYoAALBTKKEvczyRQqQgiYQAeipaVxEFs0AA7mQANbCfFkoi6AjEMh4KyuDwaLouEScwmEHlEUiETH0ZhsQUwkVijkE8nSvlyrGKqBcPgCZXC9Siyk0ukM6C8EhQdAkLB0AC2YCYKnVXKleAc9gF0JNZo9kq1spi2r9QumqvFGu5vNDutY+p4-GThojKtNaqAA).